# Error when making a photo slideshow in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, netbeans

I'm currently following a tutorial on YouTube to make a photo slide show in JavaFX. Here is my controller code:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable  {
    @FXML ImageView imageView;
    int count;
    public void slideshow()
    {
        ArrayList<Image> images= new ArrayList<Image>();
        images.add(new Image("b1.jpg"));
        images.add(new Image("b2.jpg"));
        images.add(new Image("b3.jpg"));
        Timeline timeline=new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.ofSeconds(5), event->{
             imageView.setImage(images.get(count));
             count++;
             if (count==3)
                 count=0;
        
        }));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();
    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location,ResourceBundle recourses)
    {
        slideshow();
    }
}
```

I have an error on this line:

`Timeline timeline=new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.ofSeconds(5), event->{`

I want the application to display the next image after every 5 seconds.

Comment: You imported the wrong class. You need `javafx.util.Duration`, _not_ `java.time.Duration`. Also, the method will be `Duration#seconds(double)` once you import the correct class.

Comment: You might want to move `if (count==3)
                 count=0;` before `imageView.setImage(images.get(count));
             count++;`

Comment: If that resolved the issue write it as an answer to your post and set it as the accepted answer